# How To Remove White Background On Div Caused By Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have set the background of my web page to an image by doing this

```
html {
    background: url("https://preview.ibb.co/dizdck/beach2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Then I created a div like this

```
<div class="container">hi</div>
```

The problem is that the div has a white background that I don't want to see on the page. I noticed that this white background only appears when I am using bootstrap. Any ideas on why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Here is a codepen with the example: https://codepen.io/bobnooby/pen/GExJmE

Comment: `body {
  background: none !important;
}` or without important if you write the file `link` containing this definition after other file's `link`

Comment: Personnaly i wouldnt put background on html. put it on body or even better on the div right underneath. It's a best practice if you need to do more complicated stuff like slide pages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you want to do this through `css` on the `body` :

```
body {
  background-color: red !important; //set to color
  background-image: url("https://preview.ibb.co/dizdck/beach2.jpg") !important; //or set image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally like to avoid the `!important` attribute as much as possible. My solution was to include the background image in the same tag as the `html` and `body` style attributes. this removed the white div bg color.

```css
html body {
    background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```